# js array of objects with number without property name

Tags: javascript

what's wrong with declaring this in javascript ?

```
var obj = [
    {"louis", 35},
    {"ana", 40},
    {"car", 5},
]
```

I get

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
```

Comment: Because objects need properties?

Comment: Your objects are missing the property-names

Comment: `"louis" : 35` ....

Comment: @SureshAtta, better `{name: "louis", age:35}`

Comment: `{"louis", 35}` isn't a valid JS object.  Same with the two lines that follow.  Why can't you write it this way?  Because the ECMAScript spec says NOPE.

Comment: *"objects with number without property name"* ... that isn't possible. Objects are key-value pairs. What are you trying to do exactly? If you want a list of values, use an array instead.

Comment: thanks guys ! just a convention : we cannot use number without a property name, is that right ?

Comment: You can't have values without keys in objects in general (how would you access them?) Nothing to do with numbers specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How will you access the number if you don't set the property name. If you want create an object, you should set the attribute name.

obj = [

```
{name:"louis", no:35},
{name:"ana", no:40},
{name:"car", no:5}
```

]

Can you explain the scenario where you would need this implementation?
var obj = [

```
{"louis", 35},
{"ana", 40},
{"car", 5}
```

]

**You can create a class in javascript and create instance of it:**
function initializeDetails(name,age){

```
this.name=name;
this.age=age;
```

}

[

```
new initializeDetails('louis',35),
new initializeDetails('ana',40),
new initializeDetails('car',5)
```

]

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean:

```
var obj = [
    {"louis": 35},
    {"ana": 40},
    {"car": 5}
]
```

or (even though that is not an array of objects):

```
var obj = [
    ["louis", 35],
    ["ana", 40],
    ["car", 5]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The last comma infers the presence of another item in the Array and the JS errors because it expects another item but instead finds a closing bracket.